# Generic Grouping of objects properties

Tags: ramda.js

I'm trying to group this object by name, so in fine I would be able to distinguish all names 'duval' from 'lulu':

```
const groupName = R.groupBy(R.prop('name'), [data]);
```

But this won't work on:

```
let data = {
    benj: {
        content : undefined,
        name    : 'duval',
        complete: false,
        height  : 181
    },

    joy: {
        content : undefined,
        name    : 'duval',
        complete: true
    },


    kaori: {
        content : undefined,
        name    : 'lulu',
        complete: true
    },

    satomi: {
        content : undefined,
        name    : 'lulu',
        complete: true
    }
}
```

Should I change the format of my object, or is there a way to do it in this kind of object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `[data]` to `groupBy` is not going to help much.  You want to group a list containing a single item.  The fact that that item has properties like 'bennj' and 'joy' rather than 'name' is only part of the issue.

You can get something that will work, I think, if this output would be useful:

```
{
  duval: {
    benj: {
      content: undefined,
      name: "duval",
      complete: false,
      height: 181
    },
    joy: {
      content: undefined,
      name: "duval",
      complete: true
    }
  },
  lulu: {
    kaori: {
      content: undefined,
      name: "lulu",
      complete: true
    },
    satomi: {
      content: undefined,
      name: "lulu",
      complete: true
    }
  }
}
```

But it's a bit more involved:

```
compose(map(fromPairs), groupBy(path([1, 'name'])), toPairs)(data)
```

`toPairs` converts the data to a list of elements something like this:

```
[
  "benj", 
  {
    complete: false, 
    content: undefined, 
    height: 181, 
    name: "duval"
  }
]
```

then `groupBy(path[1, 'name'])` does the grouping you're looking to do, by finding the name on the object at index 1 in this list.

And finally `map(fromPairs)` will turn these lists of lists back into objects.

It's not a particularly elegant solution, but it's fairly typical when you want to do list processing on something that's not really a list.

Comment: It seems so easy when you type. Thanks, works very well. Had I wanted to specify "any" as path, instead of targeting a specific level, is there any way to do so without a recursion ?

Comment: I can't think of any way to do that without recursion.  Someone else might have an idea.

Comment: But also the question would arise as to what your output would look like.  How would you group these arbitrarily nested objects?

Comment: Indeed. I was thinking a case where same properties would be at same level, just as in the example, but without the need to specify the '1' level. It's as if we would replace '1' by '*' and it would produce the same output.